# Creating a matrix of plots with sns distplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am plotting 20+ features like so:

```
for col in dsd_mod["ae_analysis"].columns[:len(dsd_mod["ae_analysis"].columns)]:
    if col != "sae_flag":
        sns.distplot(dsd_mod["ae_analysis"].loc[(dsd_mod["ae_analysis"]['sae_flag'] == 1),col],
                color='r',
                kde=True,
                hist=False,
                label='sae_ae = 1')
        sns.distplot(dsd_mod["ae_analysis"].loc[(dsd_mod["ae_analysis"]['sae_flag'] == 0),col],
                color='y',
                kde=True,
                hist=False,
                label='sae_ae = 0')
```

Which creates a separate graph for each feature. How can I put these all on a matrix? Or like how pair plots outputs?

Right now I get 30 graphs like this all in one column:
[image]

How can I modify this so that I can get 6 rows and 5 columns ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @brainfuck4d - Sorry, how do you mean format it?

Comment: Well now it is formatted thanks to @ImportanceOfBeingErnest :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`displot` can use whatever axes object you want to draw the plot. So you just need to create your axes with the desired geometry, and pass the relevant axes to your functions.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(6,5)
# axs is a 2D array with shape (6,5)
# you can keep track of counters in your for-loop to place the resulting graphs
# using ax=axs[i,j]
# or an alternative is to use a generator that you can use to get the next axes
# instance at every step of the loop
ax_iter = iter(axs.flat)
for _ in range(30):
    ax = next(ax_iter)
    sns.distplot(np.random.normal(loc=0, size=(1000,)), ax=ax)
    sns.distplot(np.random.normal(loc=1, size=(1000,)), ax=ax)
```

[image]